# Is it possible to specify sorting order to MySQL index?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I have a `items` table with `category_id` field.
There is a specific rule to order the items by `category_id`.
I usually sort the data like this:

```
SELECT * FROM items ORDER BY FIELD(category_id, 2, 5, 1, 4, 3)
-- In this example, the "rule" is sorting in order of (2, 5, 1, 4, 3)
```

In this case, simply creating an index on `category_id` field does not work to speed up sorting items, because the index sorts the category_id just ascending like (1, 2, 3, 4, 5).

Is it possible to specify the sorting rule when I `CREATE INDEX` on category_id field?
(And then simply `SELECT * FROM items ORDER BY category_id` works)

Or do I have to create another field like `sorted_category_id` which is sorted according to the order rule?

Comment: Use generated column and the index by it. Use this column for ordering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the column to the `items` table, with an index on it, would indeed be a solution focused on speed. By making it a *generated* column, you ensure consistency, and by making it a *virtual* column, you can move the extra data into an index (if you create it). So proceed like this:

```
ALTER TABLE items ADD (
  category_ord int GENERATED ALWAYS AS (FIELD(category_id, 2, 5, 1, 4, 3)) VIRTUAL 
);
CREATE INDEX idx_items_category_ord ON items(category_ord);

SELECT * FROM items ORDER BY category_ord;
```

### Alternative

Alternatively, the *normalised* way is to add a column to the `category` table. This will have a slight performance impact if you have many categories, but does not pose that consistency problem, and saves space. To implement that idea, proceed as follows:

If you don't have that `category` table, then create it:

```
CREATE TABLE category(
  id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  ord int NOT NULL,
  name varchar(100)
);
```

Populate the `ord` field (or whatever you want to call it) as desired:

```
INSERT INTO category(id, ord, name) VALUES
(1, 30, 'cat1'),
(2, 10, 'cat2'),
(3, 50, 'cat3'),
(4, 40, 'cat4'),
(5, 20, 'cat5');
```

And add an index on the `ord` column:

```
CREATE INDEX category_ord ON category(ord);
```

Now the query would be:

```
SELECT * 
FROM items 
INNER JOIN category 
ON items.category_id = category.id
ORDER BY category.ord;
```

The database engine can now decide to use the index on the `ord` column (or not), depending on its own analysis. If you want to force the use of it, you can use `FORCE INDEX`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM items 
INNER JOIN category FORCE INDEX category(category_ord) 
ON items.category_id = category.id
ORDER BY category.ord;
```

Note that the engine can use your index on the `items.category_id` as well, for value by value lookup.

Comment: Thank you! The alternative way is also nice when I have a separate category table.

Answer (score 0):

Like Akina says, I can use Generated Columns.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html